# in my xml file I get a caution notice on my text entry and I'd love to know how to fix it

Tags: android, text

caution [I18N] Hardcoded string"Would you like to give Zohan a call?", should use @string resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Would you like to give Zohan a call?"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not [hard code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) your strings. Instead you should put your strings in values/strings.xml.
Ctrl+1 on the error it will show you the way to fix it.
Refer to the android string documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Answer (score 0):

You should store your texts in a resource properties file and link them to your XML file using the `@` notation.

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for more information.